# Looking for website / tool / help in showing what typed Kanji on a keyboard should look like if hand written

Tags: kanji, katakana, hiragana, handwriting

Just as the title suggests, tons of Hiragana Katakana & Kanji look different when you type them on a phone compared to how one would learn to write them on pen and paper.

Is there a tool I can copy and paste Japanese sentences into, or individual kanji, and see the (as I am trying to stick to) written form with all necessary stroke arcs etc.?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a Japanese font mimicking handwriting? Like this https://www.freejapanesefont.com/category/handwriting/. I don't know if you can use it on a phone, but on a desktop you can download one of the fonts and use it to see how tour text should look written. Sort of

Comment: Or you mean like this https://kanji.sljfaq.org/kanjivg.html  (single kanji only)

Comment: Also check our topic on [Japanese Resources](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese).

Comment: Go to any website that sells a 教科書体 font and try their demo. For example [this](https://www.morisawa.co.jp/fonts/specimen/3763).